# Degenerate matrix

Tags: time-series, self-learning, matrices

I have one question which is related to showing that the $R_n$ matrix is degenerate when $n\geq 3$.

$R_n = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cos(\lambda) & \cos(2\lambda) & \cos(3\lambda) &... & \cos((n-1)\lambda) \\
cos(\lambda) & 1 & \cos(\lambda) & \cos(2\lambda) & ... & \cos((n-2)\lambda) \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
\cos((n-1)\lambda) & \cos((n-2)\lambda) & \cos((n-3)\lambda) & \cos((n-1)\lambda) & ... & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

One way is to show that this matrix is a product of matrix $A$ and its inverse, i.e.

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cos(\lambda) & 3\cos(2\lambda) & ... & \cos((n-1)\lambda)\\
0 & \sin(\lambda) & \sin(2\lambda) & ... & \sin((n-1)\lambda)
\end{pmatrix}$

Then we can see that $rang(R_n) \leq min(rang(A^{-1}),rang(A))$. Here $0\leq\lambda\leq \pi.$

Maybe there is another approach to show that the matrix $R_n$ is degenerate when $n\geq3$ ?

Comment: [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) reduces the problem to the case $n=3,$ which yields to direct calculation and application of the duplication formulas for sine and cosine.

Comment: @whuber I have one question.  Sylvester's Criterion is applied to Hermitian matrices. So in other words are we just assuming that the imaginary part is $0$ or are we using (somehow) Euler's formula? I fully understood the statement of this criterion but I'm a little confused why we can apply it to this matrix. By the way, thank you for your help!

Comment: Assuming $\lambda$ is a real number (which is strongly implied by the context and the [tag:time-series] tag you have applied), this is a real symmetric matrix and Sylvester's criterion applies.

Comment: @whuber thank you! I've edited my post, i.e. added interval for $\lambda$ values.